# How do I generate a column that indicates the proportion of male students in a class?

Tags: r, dplyr, percentage

How do I generate a column that indicates the proportion of male students in a class?
I have a table that looks like this.

```
df <- “class    id  score   year    gender
A   100 90  2000    F
A   101 80  2001    M
A   102 90  2002    M
A   102 90  2003    M
A   100 96  2003    F
B   103 75  2000    F
B   104 98  2001    M
B   105 78  2002    M
B   103 80  2003    F
B   104 54  2004    M
B   105 98  2005    M
C   106 65  2003    F
C   107 49  2004    F
C   108 38  2005    M
C   108 43  2006    M"

Data <- read.table(text=df, header = TRUE)
```

I've tried something like this. I grouped it by year, hoping that it'd account for the student and year--in other words, if a student has test scores in two different years, the student won't be counted as two different students.

```
Data %>% 
  group_by(class, year) %>% 
  mutate(prop_male = (gender=="M")/sum(gender=="F",gender=="M")) %>%
  arrange(class)
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"
```

Comment: You said " if a student has test scores in two different years, the student won't be counted as two different students". For instance, the student (id = 102) appear in 2002 and 2003. Which case do you want to retain?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```r
Data %>% 
  mutate(prop_male = (gender=="M")/sum(gender=="F",gender=="M")) %>%
  group_by(class, year) %>% 
  arrange(class)
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, we can use `prop.table` with `table` to get proportions

```
prop.table(table(Data$class, Data$gender), 1)

#         F      M
#  A 0.4000 0.6000
#  B 0.3333 0.6667
#  C 0.5000 0.5000
```

If you need only values for "Male" students, you can subset it

```
prop.table(table(Data$class, Data$gender), 1)[, "M"]
#     A      B      C 
#0.6000 0.6667 0.5000
```

---

Using `dplyr`, we can `group_by` `Class` and calculate the proportions.

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%  group_by(class) %>% summarise(perc = mean(gender == "M"))

#  class  perc
#  <fct> <dbl>
#1 A     0.6  
#2 B     0.667
#3 C     0.5
```

Comment: Does this capture grouping per year?

Comment: @hy9fesh I don't think so. This gives proportion of Male students in a `class`.  Can you show how will your expected output look like ?